# Correctly Scraping and Displaying Japanese Characters using Python Django BeautifulSoup and Curl

Tags: python, django, utf-8, beautifulsoup, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to scrape a page in japanese using python, curl, and BeautifulSoup. I then save the text to a MySQL database that's using utf-8 encoding, and display the resulting data using Django.

Here is an example URL:

https://www.cisco.apply2jobs.com/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.showJob&RID=930026&CurrentPage=180

I have a function I use to extract the HTML as a string:

```
def get_html(url):
    c = Curl()
    storage = StringIO()
    c.setopt(c.URL, str(url))
    cookie_file = 'cookie.txt'
    c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, cookie_file)
    c.setopt(c.COOKIEJAR, cookie_file)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    return storage.getvalue()
```

I then pass it to BeautifulSoup:

```
html = get_html(str(scheduled_import.url))
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

It is then parsed and saved it to a database. I then use Django to output the data to json. Here is the view I'm using:

```
def get_jobs(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all().only(*fields)
    joblist = []
    for job in jobs:
        job_dict = {}
        for field in fields:
            job_dict[field] = getattr(job, field)
        joblist.append(job_dict)
    return HttpResponse(dumps(joblist), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

The resulting page displays bytecode such as:

xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xa3\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88
\xe8\x81\xb7\xe5\x8b\x99\xe5\x86\x85\xe5\xae\xb9
\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x82\xb3\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x82\xba\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x82\xb3\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x9c\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xa7\xe3\x83\xb3\xe4\xba\x8b\xe6\xa5\xad\xe9\x83\xa8\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xba\xba\xe3\x82\x92\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\xbf\x83\xe3\x81\xa8\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\xb3\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x83\xa5\xe3\x83\x8b\xe3\x82\xb1\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xa7\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x82\x88\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\

Instead of japanese.

I've been researching all day and have converted my DB to utf-8, tried decoding the text from iso-8859-1 and encoding to utf-8.

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing and would appreciate any help or suggestions I can get so I can avoid spending another day trying to figure this out.

Comment: You forgot to tell Beautiful Soup the encoding. Get it from the response headers.

Comment: i believe the BeautifulSoup automatically sets the encoding based on the page's meta tag, according to this http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html "A <META> tag may specify an encoding for the document." and soup.originalEncoding outputs 'iso-8859-1'

Comment: You're assuming that the page *has* a META tag to read.

Comment: in this case it does, should've mentioned that

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I have the same trouble to decode japanese words with bs4

Answer (score 0):

The examples you posted are somehow the ascii representation of the string. You need to convert this into a python unicode string. Usually you can use [string encoding and decoding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to do the job. If you are not sure which one is the correct way simply experiment with it in the python console.

Try `my_new_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')` to get the python unicode string. This should correctly display in Django templates, can be saved to the DB etc.. As an example you can also just try `print my_new_string` and will see it is outputting Japanese characters.

Comment: not having any luck with this. i can get the original HTML string to display the japanese characters when i print it in console, the best i can do with the beautifulsoup output is get funky characters such as "ã&euro;?ã&fnof;?ã&sbquo;¸ã&sbquo;·ã&fnof;§ã&fnof;³ã&euro;&lsquo;<br />ã&euro;&euro;ã&fnof;»人äº&lsaquo;äº&lsaquo;å&lsaquo;&trade;æ&lsaquo;&hellip;å½&ldquo;<br /><br />ã&euro;?æ&permil;&euro;å±&#x17E;é&fnof;¨署å??"